# How to validate file data with Hive table data?

Tags: scala, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to fetch a csv file which contains list of tables in a databases and rows and columns in each table  and compare with Hive tables. the intention is to match each table rows and columns in hive.

> You have log file like below. Like below many rows

```
DBName, Table name, rows, date 
=========================== 
bigdata, emp, 10000,01-01-2010 
bigdata,finance,3000,03-09-2010 
bugdata,mktg,2000,10-10-2010
```

---

Now, write a program/script, to check these log file table rows are equal to Hive tables or not. If the table rows are equal print “Table rows are equal” else “Table rows are not equal” Assume that you have Hive and table names are same

i have tried multiple things to traverse through dataframe also tried also with RDD but i am unable to pick each record of file and compare with each table in hive using SCALA.

what i have tried:

```
 val sc = new SparkContext()
    val readFileDB= sc.textFile("/databases.csv")
    val mapData= readFileDB.map(l=>l.split(",")).map(c=>(c(0),c(1),c(2)))
    val filterData = mapData.foreach{
      case (dbname,table,rows)=> spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase(dbname)
     }
```

Comment: Create a dataframe `df1` out of your CSV and `df2` out of your hive table. `df1.except(df2)` should give you the rows that exist in df1 and not in df2. We also have `subtract` and `intersect`. You can pick based on your requirement.

Comment: hey thanks for the quick revert. will try this out .. but i hope you got me right.. i have edited my question please check it once.

Comment: Do you want to check it individually for each row and print if each row matches or not ??

Comment: yes i want to compare each row(table) of CSV data with each table in hive to compare its rows and columns

Comment: any help from experts here will be much appreciated !! plz let me know how to do this